# Is there a regular expression that return substrings from a string, that do not match a given list of specific substrings?

Tags: regex, string, pumping-lemma, context-free-language

Hi I am wondering if there is a regular expression that can do the following:

Select all the substrings from a  string that :

- start with `&` and
- have *n* number of characters after the `&`  (*n* >= 0)

AND those substrings are NOT

- `&amp;`
- `&apos;`
- `&lt;`
- `&gt;` or
- `&quot;`

For example, given the string

```
&apos;Stewie &amp; Brian    &partners in crime;&apos;
```

is there a regex that will return  only the substring    `&partners` ?

My intuition says no , because I need a context free grammar but how can I prove that? 
Is there a regex to test it with the pumping lemma ?

Or a regex actually exists and my intuition is just wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, I've taken the liberty to reformat your post. By placing short texts between backticks, you can format them as code (so you don't need to insert a space between `&` and `apos;` in order to keep the literal text). Longer texts and multi-line code samples can be formatted that way by indenting them by four spaces. Both can be achieved by selecting the text and pressing Ctrl-K. You might want to look at the editor help for more of these formatting tips. Aside from that, welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
&(?!(amp|apos|lt|gt);)\S{4,}
```

for n=4

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/Qw3cerfbEP).

The key here is the negative look ahead `(?!(amp|apos|lt|gt);)`, which asserts (without consuming input) that the input immediately following does *not* match `(amp|apos|lt|gt);`